# How and why did the Tailed Beasts grow up?

Tags: naruto

From the start of the series, we saw the Tailed Beasts as large, vicious, and angry entities bound inside the bodies of their *jinchuriki*. They were shown to despise the humans who bound them and used their power for personal gain. But they weren't always like this.

Initially, they were shown as small and emotionally open towards the Sage of Six Paths. While I understand why they hate humans *now*, I don't understand why and how they grew larger from their small size to something equivalent to an 'adult size'?

They are now shown as a large mass of chakra. When they die, they reform. Also, as we have seen, when the *Kyuubi* was divided into two separate parts, his size was reduced. But that reduction in chakra didn't make him small again.

So can anyone explain:

1. How did the Tailed Beasts grow from chibi to adult size? (Do they grow up like normal animals?)
2. Also, do chibi Tailed Beasts have less power and chakra than their adult forms?

Comment: Re their size, it's been shown in both manga and anime series that the Tailed Beasts can change size, shape and appearance (to an extent) at will. Since they don't have physical bodies, their form is much more fluid than biological organisms. So the 'chibi' Beasts could simply be a form they liked to take around S6P, representing their feelings as being his 'children' of sorts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would just be my best guess from reading the series thus far and also outside influences, but I think that the chakra which form the tailed beasts also have a psychic impression with which humans communicate and interact. This psychic impression, through experience, grows what we perceive as a personality and has its re/actions based on this.

The physical form (and perceived growth) they take on may also be due to human influence. As they have interacted with the species over time they have noted that these creatures grow old and die. Not only this, but they start from an infant form and, over time, change in height, temperament, and language ability.

Since the entire lives of the tailed beasts since the death of the Sage of the Six Paths is not detailed it is impossible to know when the tailed beasts saw different levels of maturity. I would also guess that this would have a human influence as well, but mostly from the jinchuuriki (human hosts) that the beasts dwelled within. As the hosts grew older and died this possibly reflected within how the beasts manifested themselves as they moved from host to host over the generations. It is also through seeing the lives of these human hosts and what their role in society was that contributed to their sour feelings towards the human species.

As for the chibi tailed beast having less power? If we consider all beings within this universe start out with no manual to their powers and not a lot of instruction we can also infer that the tailed beasts came into existence not knowing the extent of their power. I say "extent of their power" only because after the corruption of ninshu into ninjutsu that the techniques we think of as powers came about as a concept. The tailed beasts most likely have had the same chakra reserves as before but started life without the desire to use them as humans would.

Comment: this seems possible. but I'll wait for some other more fact based answer if there is any.